# Using PHP Wrapper Tags (<?php ?>)

Tags: php

Coming from C++/C/C# the use of the  tags keeps nagging at me. When writing php scripts inside a php file, do the tags have to be around EVERYTHING, or is there any special syntax for outside of these tags? Also, can there be multiple sets of tags within the same file (even if it's against convention).

Comment: I can't see what this has to do with C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, tags should be around every block of PHP code. There is multiple ways of doing this, one way would be doing an entire file in PHP, eg.

```
<?php
    $var = "my text";
    echo '<html>';
        echo '<head>';
        echo '</head>';
        echo '<body>';
            echo '<p>' . $var . '</p>';
        echo '</body>';
    echo '</html>';
?>
```

Another way would be to do it all inline

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><?php $var = "my text"; echo $var; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

As far as I'm aware, there's not really a preferred convention, many people do one or the other, or both, depending on how much php is required. This information is what you would really find from ANY php tutorial site, and is not really suitable for Stack Overflow.

But regarding your question of whether all php needs to be in the `<?php ?>` tags, the answer is yes, that's how the server knows where to compute code before sending the file off to a request.

edit:
php will also keep track of values after the tag has closed. One block of tags does not work the same as curly brackets in C oriented programs, so in the following case:

```
<?php
    $var = "text"
?>

...

<?php
    echo $var;
?>
```

the output would still be `text`.

This also applies to functions in php, so if you have

```
<?php
    function myFunction(){
        $var = "text";
        ?>
        <li>
        <?php
        echo $var;
    }
?>
```

It won't break out of the function because you closed the tag.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at a bunch of tutorial sites, but most never said WHY the tags were used, just that they were used. I was mostly looking for what they actually did, this makes much more sense then.

Comment: Note the edit for more information about the tags.

Comment: Would that be valid syntax for either of them (or would it simply not work? I see why you'd not want to do it, but would the system LET you do it, or just start on fire?

Comment: In the second edit, it is completely valid (and sometimes a good option, but not often). The first edit is also completely valid, and a lot of the times a good choice. For example, if you have some initial php computation and then a large chunk of pure html, it's not always best to just echo out all the html.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, so the tags are mostly just to state that you're doing PHP, and anything outside is just like plain text.. Ok that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

PHP is designed to be embedded into web pages. So the way it works is that it simply copies its input file to the output, until it encounters the `<?php` tag. Anything inside this is executed as PHP code. When it sees `?>`, it goes back to copying mode. So all executable code has to be inside `<?php ?>`, and verbatim text can be outside it.

Coming from C, just think of everything outside the tags as a big `printf()` statement.

Comment: Oh, that makes much more sense.